# How to access the whole screen in x64 assembly, without BIOS or C

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86-64, vga, brainfuck

I'm currently working on an operating system. I have written an interpreter (which is also a compiler, oddly enough, but that's not the point). I basically did everything; I just need to build a GUI. I wrote my own language for handling that too, but I can't access the whole screen, and when I try to, it crashes. The code looks like this:

```
...
   mov ax,118h
    mov     bx,ax
    mov     ax,4f02h
    int     16

(entering 64 bit)
(some of my language)

ou:
sub r11, 2 ;this is part of my brainfuck interpreter, it takes the 3 bytes of color of the current and previous two bytes.
mov al, [r11]
mov ah, 00000000b
mov edx, 1111111111111111b
mul edx
add eax, edx
inc eax
mov ax, 0000000000000000b
mov ecx, eax
inc r11
mov cl, [r11]
mov ch, cl
inc r11
mov cl, [r11]
jmp ouu

...


ouu:

;mov ecx,  00000000111111111111111110001000b (This is just for debugging)

mov rax, 1024

mul r8 ;y coordinate
add rax, rdx


add rax, r9 ;x coordinate

mov rdx, 3
mul rdx
add rax, rdx

    mov rdi,rax
   mov [0a0000h+rax], rcx

   stosb
```

If you want to see the whole code, I can send it to you personally, but since nobody ever programmed a brainfuck OS and it's so compact (it's not even a kilobyte with everything), I want to be secretive with this till I finish it.

It currently has 24 bit graphics (real color), no push or pop, no BIOS after 16 bits, no kernel, and no C. It's the barest program you can ever write. And I'm trying to make it compatible with all resolutions (I mean, even with 8K). But I have to access the whole screen, and most people use C or some type of kernel, so I couldn't find an answer to do this. So basically, I need to do pageing. Can somebody help with my crazy project?

Comment: If you want to support all resolutions, the easiest way is to use VBE.  Be aware that it's still quite complex to set up.  You could also boot via EFI and use the EFI framebuffer instead.

Comment: You provided no [mcve] or even a meaningful description of how your code is structured. You don't want to use C or assembly, so what do you want to use? You first need to make an environment where your BF interpreter can run abstractly from the HW. You also don't seem very proficient in writing assembly and don't seem to have a good understanding of how HW works (you surely didn't think a 1024x768x24bpp could fit in the standard VGA range and you definitively don't want to use bank switching). So it's hard to help you with your secret project you don't want to talk about.

Comment: I programmed the whole thing in x64 assembly (how to access the whole screen IN x64 assembly without BIOS or C). The BF interpreter is already in use. And I wrote the whole BF interpreter myself, so I'm confident programming in assembly. And I don't use HW; it's straight, raw assembly. But I'm new to the graphics stuff; I know that VGA does not support high resolutions; I just want to make it compatible with all types of monitors, like Windows or like every other OS. I just realised there is no direct messages so I have to put the link here. (next comment) @MargaretBloom

Comment: Whole os: https://github.com/Xulum12/assembly/blob/main/FOS%20Nonworking%201.0 
@MargaretBloom

Comment: I thought about using UEFI, or EFI, But that would cut off almost every old computer. And I want it to be compatible with all hardware so BIOS is the best option for me. @fuz

Comment: @Xulum12 Then you'll have to use VBE I guess.  That is the main way to portably access arbitrary graphics modes.  Please node that VBE requires 32 bit to work, so you may have to create a 32 bit task for doing VBE calls.  Your OS can run in 64 bit mode of course.

Comment: You can use VBE to set up a linear framebuffer and then stick to that. Note that VBE is older than long mode so if you want to use the latter you can assume the former (or fallback to standard VGA). [OSDev explains how to use VBE](https://wiki.osdev.org/VESA_Video_Modes). You can set up the LFB before switching to protected mode. Note that both VBE and the UEFI GOP are slow. Think of Windows without graphic drivers slow. Coupled with plain BF, which slows things even more, it will be hard to have a smooth UI. Don't expect too much from these interfaces.

Comment: That is coded in C. I need assembly. I can't find any assembly code anywhere. I did research for hours, but I can't find any piece of linear framebuffer that is compatible with my OS. @MargaretBloom

Comment: Iterating the mode table is not necessarily fun, but it's hardly rocket science. Surely you can translate that C code to asm in no time.